# As a beginner, how to select spring dependencies in `Maven Repository`?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

[Spring framework](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework) has so many dependencies in `Maven Repository`. As a beginner, I'm really ***confused*** about so many dependencies, and I don't know which are really need. In other words, what is the specific function of these dependencies? :(

Thanks!

[[image: Spring framework screenshots]]

Comment: spring core,web will do the basic job :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should definitely go on the Spring website (https://spring.io/guides) and try the guides, it will tell you what to use according to what you wanna do

Indeed, the Spring-core is the most important part, but too basic, so you'll have to add other dependencies to help you

If you want, you can message me, so I could help you